# How to enumerate combined strings as the search range of for..in loop?

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I worked out a code that make sense to me but not python since I'm new to python.

Check my code here:

```
checksum_algos = ['md5','sha1']

for filename in ["%smanifest-%s.txt" % (prefix for prefix in ['', 'tag'],  a for a in checksum_algos)]:
  f = os.path.join(self.path, filename)
  if isfile(f):
     yield f
```

My intention is to search filename in a list like :

`['manifest-md5.txt','tagmanifest-md5.txt','manifest-sha1.txt','tagmanifest-sha1.txt']`

but I got `syntax` problem to implement it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

```
for filename in ("%smanifest-%s.txt" % (prefix, a)
    for prefix in ['', 'tag'] for a in checksum_algos):
```

Comment: `str.__mod__()` doesn't take tuples of generators, so it wouldn't work logically.

Answer (score 1):

Or you need [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools

>>> [i for i in itertools.product(('', 'tag'), ('sha', 'md5'))]
[('', 'sha'), ('', 'md5'), ('tag', 'sha'), ('tag', 'md5')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using new style string formatting and `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product
["{0}manifest-{1}.txt".format(i,e) for i,e in  product(*(tags,checksum_algos))]
```

**out:**

```
['manifest-md5.txt',
 'manifest-sha1.txt',
 'tagmanifest-md5.txt',
 'tagmanifest-sha1.txt']
```